# Systemd: How do I make sure one unit doesn't run if another is?

Tags: systemd

I have "serviceA" and "serviceB". "serviceA" is run every 12 hours with a timer and "serviceB" is every 15 minutes.  I want to ensure that "serviceA" is never ran if "serviceB" is currently running, vice versa. I also want to make sure that "serviceA" doesn't kill "serviceB" if it's triggered and "serviceB" is currently running.

How can I do this with systemd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [ExecStartPre](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStartPre=):

From the manpage ExecStartPre entry:

> If any of those commands (not prefixed with "-") fail, the rest are not executed and the unit is considered failed.

### serviceA

```
[Unit]
Description=Service A 12 hours on timer

[Service]
Type=oneshot
# Check and see if serviceB is running
ExecStartPre="! systemctl is-active --quiet serviceB"
Restart=no
...
```

### serviceB

```
[Unit]
Description=Service B 15 mins on timer

[Service]
Type=oneshot
# Check and see if serviceA is running
ExecStartPre="! systemctl is-active --quiet serviceA"
Restart=no
...
```

### Conflicts

If you use the `Conflicts` directive, the service or services specified will be stopped when the service with the directive is set is started. You mentioned:

> I also want to make sure that "serviceA" doesn't kill "serviceB" if it's triggered and "serviceB" is currently running.

However from the manpage it appears this this is a two way relationship:

> If a unit has a Conflicts= setting on another unit, starting the former will stop the latter and vice versa.

So you will have to avoid the Conflicts directive.